# Explain memory profiler observation. Advice in memory profiling of WP8 apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, memory-leaks, profiling

I've stuck with memory profiling of WP8 application. I am trying to detect the cause of memory leak when user navigate from page 1 to page 2 (page 2 has WebBrowser control on it) and back to page 1 repeatedly. To figure out where memory leak is, I am using Windows Phone Application Analysis from Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. I've read several articles about memory profiling using WPAA, including series of articles:

- [Memory Profiling for Application Performance](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/02/01/memory-profiling-for-application-performance.aspx)
- [Memory Profiling: Launching, Graphs and Markers](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/04/19/memory-profiling-launching-graphs-and-markers.aspx)
- [Memory Profiling: The Heap Summary view](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/05/10/memory-profiling-the-heap-summary-view.aspx)
- [Memory Profiling: The Types View](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/08/17/memory-profiling-the-types-view.aspx)
- [Memory Profiling: The Instances View](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/08/24/memory-profiling-the-instances-views.aspx)
- [Memory Profiling: The Methods View](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/09/07/memory-profiling-the-methods-view.aspx)
- [Memory Profiling: The Object Graph View](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/24/memory-profiling-the-object-graph-view.aspx)

I've done several memory profiler sessions and found out observations I can't explain and understand. According to memory profiler's Heap Summary total memory went down in selected time range, but according to graph - memory usage significantly grown, I can't understand data obtained using memory profiler taking into account knowledge I have so far in memory analysis. Here is a screenshot of profiler's session.

[image: Unexplainable profiler's data]

- Does anybody know what kind of problem could possible cause such a strange profiler's observation?
- What to next taking into account observed data, should I continue looking for leak in visual controls or non-visual objects?

Comment: did you get any idea about this? I am facing the same issue. The graph shows a usage of 100+MB but the heap summary only shows a couple MBs (or KBs). Let me know if you learned anything more about how to analyze memory profiling report

Comment: @SagarSodah unfortunately I do not remember if I've managed to overcome WP8 profiler results. Since then I've moved to UWP, but not yet played with it's memory profiler because it's a bit harder to have memory issue on Windows 10, since there are only 1Gb+ devices upgradeable to Windows 10 Mobile.